# Charts not loading out data for my django project

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-views, chart.js

So, I've been trying to get my charts to display packages created per hour, but it doesn't render out the data on the chart. The axes display though. When I use print statements in the view, it returns an empty array for the hours, despite the same code working for a different project

```
def warehouse_dashboard(request):
    user = request.user

    if user.role == 'warehouse_admin':
        warehouse = user.warehouse_admin_field

        if warehouse:
            buses = Bus.objects.filter(warehouse=warehouse)

            # Filter items that are either assigned to a bus or have a delivery status of "Ready"
            packages_coming = Item.objects.filter(
                Q(station_to=warehouse, bus_number_plate__isnull=False) | Q(station_to=warehouse, delivery_status='Ready')
            ).exclude(delivery_status__in=['Canceled', 'Received', 'Ready'])

            packages_leaving = Item.objects.filter(station_from=warehouse).exclude(delivery_status='Canceled')

            packages_by_bus = {}
            for bus in buses:
                packages_from = Item.objects.filter(
                    Q(station_from=warehouse) | Q(station_to=warehouse), bus_number_plate=bus
                ).exclude(delivery_status='Canceled')
                packages_by_bus[bus] = packages_from

            bus_count = buses.count()
            packages_count_coming = packages_coming.count()
            packages_count_leaving = packages_leaving.count()

            # Retrieve data for the graph (daily packages added)
            # Get the datetime for the start of the current day
            current_day_start = timezone.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

            hourly_totals = Item.objects.filter(
                station_from=warehouse,
                creation_date__gte=current_day_start
            ).annotate(hour=ExtractHour('creation_date')).values('hour').annotate(total=Count('id')).order_by('hour')

            # Initialize an array to hold the data for each hour of the day
            chart_data = [0] * 24

            for total in hourly_totals:
              hour = total['hour']
              if hour is not None:
                  chart_data[hour] = total['total']
                  print(chart_data[hour])

                
            # Get the number of days in the current month
            current_month = timezone.now().month
            days_in_month = calendar.monthrange(timezone.now().year, current_month)[1]

            # Get the datetime for the start of the current month
            current_month_start = timezone.now().replace(day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
            month_name = current_month_start.strftime('%B')

            daily_totals = Item.objects.filter(
                station_from=warehouse,
                creation_date__gte=current_month_start
            ).annotate(day=ExtractDay('creation_date')).values('day').annotate(total=Count('id')).order_by('day')

            # Initialize an array to hold the data for each day of the month
            chart_data_month = [0] * days_in_month

            for total in daily_totals:
              day = total['day']
              if day is not None:
                  day -= 1  # Adjust the day to match array indices (start from 0)
                  chart_data_month[day] = total['total']
                  print(chart_data_month[day])



            packages_in_transit_count = 0

            if request.method == 'POST':
                item_id = request.POST.get('item_id')  # Get the item_id from the submitted form
                if item_id:
                    item = get_object_or_404(Item, id=item_id)
                    item.delivery_status = 'Received'
                    item.save()

            context = {
                'warehouse': user,
                'packages_leaving': packages_leaving,
                'packages_coming': packages_coming,
                'packages_by_bus': packages_by_bus,
                'bus_count': bus_count,
                'packages_count_coming': packages_count_coming,
                'packages_count_leaving': packages_count_leaving,
                'packages_in_transit_count': packages_in_transit_count,
                'buses': buses,
                'month_name': month_name,
                'chart_data_packages': {
                    "chart_type": "bar",
                    "x_values": list(range(24)),  # Hours of the day (0 to 23)
                    "datasets": [
                        {
                            "label": "Packages Added per Hour for Today",
                            "data": chart_data,  # Use the dynamic data here
                            "backgroundColor": 'red',
                            "borderColor": 'red',
                            "borderWidth": 1,
                        }
                    ],
                    "chart_title": 'Packages Per Hour',
                    "x_title": 'Hour of the Day',
                    "y_title": 'Number of Packages'
                },
                'chart_data_month_packages': {
                  "chart_type": "bar",
                  "x_values": [day for day in range(1, days_in_month + 1)],  # Days of the month (1 to last day)
                  "datasets": [
                      {
                          "label": f"Packages Added per Day in {month_name}",
                          "data": chart_data_month,  # Use the dynamic data here
                          "backgroundColor": 'green',
                          "borderColor": 'green',
                          "borderWidth": 1,
                      }
                  ],
                  "chart_title": f"Packages Per Day in {current_month}",
                  "x_title": 'Day of the Month',
                  "y_title": 'Number of Packages'
              },
            }

            return render(request, 'warehouse/warehouse_dashboard.html', context)
        else:
            # Handle the case where the user is a warehouse admin without an assigned warehouse
            message = "You don't have an assigned warehouse."
            return render(request, "pages/index.html", {'message': message})
    else:
        return render(request, 'warehouse/warehouse_dashboard.html', context)
```

and this chart is called in the template in this format:

```
<script>
    function draw_chartjs_chart(
      chart_type,
      canvas_id,
      x_values,
      datasets,
      chart_title,
      x_title,
      y_title
    ) {
      var ctx = document.getElementById(canvas_id).getContext("2d");
      new Chart(ctx, {
        type: chart_type,
        data: {
          labels: x_values,
          datasets: datasets,
        },
        options: {
          responsive: true,
          maintainAspectRatio: false,
          plugins: {
            legend: {
              display: true,
              position: "bottom",
            },
          },
          scales: {
            x: {
              display: true, // This will display the x-axis scale
              title: {
                display: true,
                text: x_title,
              },
            },
            y: {
              display: true, // This will display the y-axis scale
              title: {
                display: true,
                text: y_title,
              },
              ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                stepSize: 1,
                precision: 0, // Customize the step size as needed
              },
            },
          },
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: chart_title,
          },
        },
      });
    }
    
    function plotCharts() {
          var mydata = {{ chart_data_packages|safe }}
          draw_chartjs_chart(
              mydata.chart_type, "myChart", mydata.x_values, mydata.datasets,
              mydata.chart_title, mydata.x_title, mydata.y_title
          );
          var myMonthData = {{ chart_data_month_packages|safe }}
          draw_chartjs_chart(
              myMonthData.chart_type, "myMonthChart", myMonthData.x_values, myMonthData.datasets,
              myMonthData.chart_title, myMonthData.x_title, myMonthData.y_title
          );
      }
    
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      plotCharts();
    });
  
    
  
  </script>
```